# Effective resistance of an infinite circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Here is the infinite series[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dQcM.jpg)

[image: Here is the question]

My solution is wrong because the denominator of the fraction in the first equation is $1/R$ when in the correct answer, you can see it is $1/2R$. I can't seem to find out why or how they obtained $1/2R$ though, since the effective resistance is infinite.

[image: Here is the solution]

Answer (score 1):

R is the resistance between A and B. If you imagine removing the three 1 Ohm resistances and measuring the resistance before the 2 Ohm resistances, you have exactly the same configuration but with all the resistance values doubled, so 2R.

Comment: Thank you!! I see what you mean, so the sum of this second infinite series is technically double of the first, helped me a lot :)